# How to require two properties to be set at the same time?

Tags: typescript

I want to make sure that two nullable properties of a class of TS objects are always set (not null) at the same time. The only solution I have come up with is this but I have the strong suspicion that this is not the most elegant way to do this:

```js
class MyClass {
    private property1: string | null = null;
    private property2: string | null = null;

    setProperties(property1: string, property2: string) {
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    getProperty1() {
        return this.property1;
    }

    getProperty2() {
        return this.property2;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQA4CcBLANzABcBTPfAe1wvzPgEYAuaCMogOwHNoAPtG4BXECGgBeYWJABuLDgIlyVAnQZMATO049+Q0eKkzxCxdggUyABVr1GhChAAU6h0zYcuhPgBpqDUZ4HW99AEp0CxxsMgALQggAOndNFhNU4OYFGJj4xJT7NK0MouCtHJwAXwxo3ms7IM8XSMxcnHxrEXxuaHzkzM9K7Bq6hrLtFqj27E6ybt7+wqaQ4egaqqA)

Thanks in advance for the help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have numeric-indexed properties, I'd use an array of properties instead, and you can type them as `private props: string[] | null[] = [null, null];`:

```
class MyClass {
    private props: string[] | null[] = [null, null];

    setProperties(property1: string, property2: string) {
        this.props = [property1, property2];
    }

    getProperty1() {
        return this.props[0];
    }

    getProperty2() {
        return this.props[1];
    }
}
```

When you have a collection of property names which aren't numeric-indexed, use an object:

```
class MyClass {
    private props: { propfoo: string, propbar: string } | { propfoo: null, propbar: null } = { propfoo: null, propbar: null };

    setProperties(propfoo: string, propbar: string) {
        this.props = { propfoo, propbar };
    }

    getPropFoo() {
        return this.props.propfoo;
    }

    getPropBar() {
        return this.props.propbar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or an object union would work as well.. would be more clear IMO, especially if the number of props grow

Comment: Why type it as an array instead of a tuple?

Comment: @ritaj Typing it as a tuple would be a bit repetitive. Not that bad, but an array is more easily extensible if there are more properties.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir If the properties are numeric-indexed like in OP's code, an array is probably a lot better than an object, but if they can have any arbitrary name, yes, an object would be better.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for the suggestion but I don't understand what you mean with an object union. Just a normal JS object?

Comment: @lx4r He means something like `{ prop1: string, prop2: string } | { prop1: null, prop2: null }`. Good if you have properties of varied names, but the array is better if you have numeric-indexed properties like here

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ah, thanks. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I just meant for the property names to be placeholders for arbitrary names, my bad. I'll go with an object then, thanks (also to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir).
Could you maybe add the object suggestion to your answer so that it's easier for people to find? That would be awesome :).